# Copy a file across Box accounts

Tags: box-api

I am working on integrating my application with Box. I am providing a way for a user to send files to the server, and the server will upload to a managed enterprise Box account.

I would like to support users who already have a file in Box so that they can select a file from their Box account and transfer it to the server's Box account. I can do this by having the user download the file, upload it to the server, and having the server upload it to its Box account.

It seems silly to download and re-upload the file. Is there a way to simply copy the file from the user account to the server's account (with the user's approval)?

Comment: +1 I would also find this super great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say you have user A and user B.  If you want to copy a file from user A's "outbox" folder to user B's "inbox" folder.  You can do it one of two ways.

Either user B can make user A a collaborator with Editor access to the "inbox" folder.  Then from user A's account they can do the copy API (POST /files//copy [documentation here](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-copy-a-file)) and "push" the file into B's inbox.

Or

Via a "pull" model.  User A can give user B access to their "outbox" folder, and user B can run the copy API, and copy the content to their "inbox" folder.

Comment: Thanks. A few notes for others in this situation: The 'Uploader' role that my server would assign with the 'push' model means my users could see everyone else's file names. The 'pull' model means the action happens outside of the application and will require extra layers to notify the user of success or failure.